# Firebase hosting - connecting domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a react app to a domain that I own.  Currently that domain takes you to a wordpress site of mine.  I want the new app to replaced the wordpress site.

I'm on my firebase dashboard and trying to connect the app to the domain.  It wants me to verify it by adding a DNS TXT record, which I did.

It's saying they don't match, but they do.  The only difference is it says it is expecting "value: blah-blah-blah" but it found "values: blah-blah-blah".  Basically the difference is "value" vs. "values", and I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: Please reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) with specifics for help on this issue.

Comment: Unless you can show exactly what you entered, which provider you use, and what specific values are used, it'll be hard to help here. As Michael said [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in its current state, it requires personalized troubleshooting that most developers on Stack Overflow can't provide.